# Найти из одного Массива данные цифры

Tags: javascript

```
let a = [123, 111, 523, 687, 147852369];
let odintripyat = []; //Если в массиве let a есть цифры 1, 3, 5, то переместить в данный массив
let dvachitireshest = []; //Если в массиве let a есть цифры 2, 4, 6, то переместить в данный массив
let semvosemdevyat = []; //Если в массиве let a есть цифры 7, 8, 9, то переместить в данный массив.
```

Если что-то непонятно, попробую объяснить по-другому.

Comment: Непонятно. Какой должен быть результат для указанного массива?

Comment: Например в массиве let a = [] //Первая запись 123 то есть данная запись должна будет переместиться в массивы odintripyat и dvachitireshest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let a = [123, 111, 523, 687, 147852369];
let odintripyat = []; //Если в массиве let a есть цифры 1, 3, 5, то переместить в данный массив
let dvachitireshest = []; //Если в массиве let a есть цифры 2, 4, 6, то переместить в данный массив
let semvosemdevyat = []; //Если в массиве let a есть цифры 7, 8, 9, то переместить в данный массив.
for (let i in a) {
  let num = a[i];
  let dir = 0;
  while (num != 0 && dir != 7) {
    switch (num % 10) {
      case 1:
      case 3:
      case 5:
        dir |= 1;
        break;
      case 2:
      case 4:
      case 6:
        dir |= 2;
        break;
      case 7:
      case 8:
      case 9:
        dir |= 4;
        break;
    }
    num = Math.floor(num / 10);
  }
  if ((dir & 1) != 0)
    odintripyat.push(a[i]);
  if ((dir & 2) != 0)
    dvachitireshest.push(a[i]);
  if ((dir & 4) != 0)
    semvosemdevyat.push(a[i]);
}
console.log('1, 3, 5: ' + odintripyat);
console.log('2, 4, 6: ' + dvachitireshest);
console.log('7, 8, 9: ' + semvosemdevyat);
```

Comment: Оригинально, но плохо масштабируемо. Если задача вдруг усложнится и потребуется искать не отдельные цифры, а например, их сочетания, то возникнут некоторые затруднения. :)

Comment: @Yaant, как раз не оригинально... это типичное и разумное решение подобных задач (разве что, константы в проверках стоило вынести в массивы - это обеспечило бы гибкость, естессно в рамках задачи. `case` допускает использование выражений). Основное преимущество этого решения над вашим - скорость выполнения... и думаю что она не просто выше, а выше ***в разы***. Когда в последний раз проверял "остаток-от-деления vs регулярка", разница была восьмикратной... что весьма критично.

Comment: @yar85 Был склонен согласиться насчет скорости, регулярки - вещь не быстрая, но решил проверить, и был удивлен, мой вариант оказался немного быстрее: https://jsfiddle.net/1w6ck6o3/ Или я что-то накосячил с тестом?

Comment: @yar85 Любопытно, если увеличить длину чисел в массиве (вместо трехзначных брать шестизначные), тогда мой вариант в Chrome начинает проигрывать, а в FireFox по-прежнему работает быстрее.

Comment: @Yaant, вот тест, в котором оставлен только разбор числа:  https://jsperf.com/so-812810 . Ну, незачем ведь соревноваться в скорости чтения/записи в массив.. это уже "обвесы". Кстати, в коде Антона обнаружилась ошибка(?) в условии `while`, я добавил вариант с фиксом. В целом, ситуация с скоростью думаю ясна. Плюс еще попробовал разные варианты: ваш подход с `for` вместо `forEach` (2); и со сравнением по ключу объекта вместо констант (1, 3). Последние два варианта оказались печальны :D Кстати, справедливости ради: при тесте *с массивами, ваш код был быстрее* - видимо, V8 его мощно оптимизирует.

Comment: @yar85 Спасибо, любопытно. :) Однако интересно, в исходных вариантах с массивами, количество чтений-записей ведь одинаково, за счет чего V8 умудряется оптимизировать мой вариант, и не может подобным же образом оптимизировать вариант Антона?

Comment: @Yaant, а фиг его знает, этот V8 :) Но иначе чем оптимизацией, объяснить такой феномен я не могу... И вот еще странность: https://jsperf.com/question812810-arr/1 - когда я ночью проверял на мобиле аналогичным тестом, кейс регулярки был быстрее в обоих случаях... а сейчас они все вровень идут)) Хотя, может я где-то накриворучил...

Answer (score 2):

```js
let a = [123, 111, 523, 687, 147852369];
let odintripyat = []; //Если в массиве let a есть цифры 1, 3, 5, то переместить в данный массив
let dvachitireshest = []; //Если в массиве let a есть цифры 2, 4, 6, то переместить в данный массив
let semvosemdevyat = []; //Если в массиве let a есть цифры 7, 8, 9, то переместить в данный массив.
const checkArr = [{
  re: /[135]/,
  arr: odintripyat
}, {
  re: /[246]/,
  arr: dvachitireshest
}, {
  re: /[789]/,
  arr: semvosemdevyat
}]
a.forEach(num => {
  checkArr.forEach(obj => {
    if (obj.re.test(num + '')) obj.arr.push(num);
  })
})
console.log('123:', odintripyat);
console.log('246:', dvachitireshest);
console.log('789:', semvosemdevyat);
```

Comment: А через for или while можно как то?

Comment: Можно, но зачем?

Comment: forEach не допустимо в данном задании

Comment: Чем обусловлена недопустимость? Ну, замените `forEach` на `for (let num of a)`

Comment: А тут checkArr.forEach(obj => for(checkArr >= obj){} ?

Comment: Это сейчас Вы на полном серьезе говорите, что не знаете, как перебрать элементы массива при помощи цикла `for`?